# Postfix doesn't run in macOS Ventura

Tags: networking, postfix, email-server, mac, daemon

I have just updated my Mac to macOS Ventura. When I try to start postfix, it says "$daemon_directory/master -t 2> /dev/null postfix/postfix-script: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running". However with ps -ef | grep --color postfix I can see that nothing is running.

Any suggestions?